# Android refresh activity on close of another

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities (Activity_A > which is the parent || Activity_B > which is the child)

When I click the button_A on Activity_A to open Activity_B, this Activity_B isn't shown in full screen, it's showed  in 'android:style/Theme.Dialog'.

After that, when I click the button_B, I would like to move on Activity_A (which is open in background) refresh itself without exiting and open it again.

If I didn't put myself clear, let me know. I don't know where to start or if this is possible.

**Edit**: Solved.

I used the onResume() as suggested.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){ 
     super.onResume();
     // call function
}
```

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: when you start a new activity the previous activity (activity a) is paused, any updated to that activity should then be done in the onResume when activity B is destroyed

Answer (score 3):

You could use `startActivityForResult()` to start Activity_B like shown [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

Then in Activity_A `onActivityResult()` call a refresh() method that you have implemented depending on your "refreshing needs

Comment: If you can, mark one of the answers that helped you as correct, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to add flag into intent to tell it open the same activity and dont start a new one:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You  could add

```
<activity name="..." launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

This allow that The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

You can refer [`Activity Launch Mode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)